# Object look at target direction?

Tags: unity

How to make an object look at the target direction not at the target himself ?

```
public Transform target;

void Update() {

    transform.LookAt(target);
    float step = 2 * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"target direction"*? A specific point in space? The direction that `target` is looking at (how do you define that?)?

Comment: I mean "The direction that target is looking at"

Comment: You can't really *"look at a direction"* - you need to pick a point on the direction vector to look at. (Maybe your question is how to calculate a direction vector and pick a point on it? In that case you should update the question accordingly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one object to look parallel to the sight-direction of another object, you can simply turn it into the same rotation:

```
this.transform.rotation = target.transform.rotation;
```

But if you want one object to look at whatever *thing* another object is looking at, you first need to figure out where that other *thing* is, because the direction would differ depending on if it's something directly in front of the other object or something at the horizon.

One option is to do a [raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) from the other object to find the point where its line of sight is broken and then use `LookAt` for that point.

```
RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast(target.transform.position, target.transform.rotation.eulerAngles, out hit)) {
     this.transform.LookAt(hit.point);
}
```

Note that Physics.Raycast is only broken by objects with colliders.